# Dynamically add fragments (or appropriate component) to a list view in Android App (Kotlin)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin

I am unsure on the theory on Kotlin and Android development (Still a novice). I have a fragment with a simple score keeping element to it. It displays a score and there is a + & - button to effect the score. Below is this fragments code:

ScoreKeepingBasicFragment.kt

```
class ScoreKeepingBasicFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() =
            ScoreKeepingBasicFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var binding: ScoreKeepingBasicFragmentBinding
    private val viewModel by viewModels<ScoreKeepingBasicViewModel> {
        ScoreKeepingBasicViewModelFactory()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.score_keeping_basic_fragment,
            container,
            false
        )
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = viewModel


        return binding.root
    }
}
```

ScoreKeepingBasicViewModel.kt

```
class ScoreKeepingBasicViewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return modelClass.getConstructor().newInstance()
    }
}

class ScoreKeepingBasicViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var scoreText = MutableLiveData<String>("0")
    private var scoreInt: Int = 0


    fun addScore(){
        println("ADD")
        scoreInt++
        scoreText.value = "$scoreInt"
    }

    fun minusScore(){
        println("Minus")
        scoreInt--
        scoreText.value = "$scoreInt"
    }
}
```

score_keeping_basic_fragment.xml

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.michaelcodesthings.scorekeeper.viewmodel.ScoreKeepingBasicViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/minus_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.minusScore()}">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/left_rectangle"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_remove"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score_list_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/center_rectangle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@{viewModel.scoreText}"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/add_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.addScore()}">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/right_rectangle"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Now this fragment works exactly how I want it to, adding and taking away from a score. And works fine if I were to use the "include" tag in another fragment or activity.

But now this is where I'm lost on how Kotlin/Android Dev works. I want to have a list of these fragments on a screen, the user is able to press an "add score" button and another one of these gets added to the list, so would be dynamically adding scores to the list view. Each item in the list needs its own state and to work independently to the rest. Below is a diagram on roughly how I want it to look.

I've done some searching but have been reading you can't add fragments to list views, but haven't seem to find a solution to my problem. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Any help on how the logic works for this would be appreciated greatly. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image: Diagram on roughly how I want it to look]

[image: Score Fragment]

Answer (score 0):

> I've done some searching but have been reading you can't add fragments to list views, but haven't seem to find a solution to my problem. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Technically it is possible to add fragments to a list view with some workarounds.  However, you should not be adding fragments to a list view. 
 That is not what list views are for.  Also fragment are managed by the Activity through the FragmentManager not the list view.  You should look into making custom views and use the adapters `getViewTypeCount` and `getView` to get different list item behavior.

Here is some documentation on now to make custom views.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components

After you have a custom view, that should be what you add dynamically to your list view.